# VB.NET optimizing drag & drop code

Tags: vb.net, drag-and-drop

I'm currently struggling with drag & drop code. I have 3 images that are at the top, and I want to add them in a random order in a flow-layout-panel.

[image]

I have this code for adding the square image into the flow-layout-panel, but I have got the feeling that this is not 100% correct. Is it possible to add these with 1 sub instead of 3?

And how do you write a sub that detects what object in being dragged? Now my sub just adds a square with each dragdrop event. But I need it to drop a Square only when a Square is being dragged and drop a Trapezium or round when it's being dragged.

Public Class Form2

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
    ' Initiate dragging.
    PictureBox1.DoDragDrop(PictureBox1, DragDropEffects.Copy)
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox2_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox2.MouseMove
    ' Initiate dragging.
    PictureBox2.DoDragDrop(PictureBox2, DragDropEffects.Copy)
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox3_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox3.MouseMove
    ' Initiate dragging.
    PictureBox3.DoDragDrop(PictureBox2, DragDropEffects.Copy)
End Sub

Private Sub FlowLayoutPanel1_DragEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As _
                                       System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles FlowLayoutPanel1.DragEnter
    ' Check the format of the data being dropped.
    If (e.Data.GetDataPresent(GetType(PictureBox))) Then
        ' Display the copy cursor.
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
    Else
        ' Display the no-drop cursor.
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub FlowLayoutPanel1_DragDrop(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As _
                                      System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles FlowLayoutPanel1.DragDrop
    Dim oPB As New PictureBox()
    oPB.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\Jef\Desktop\square.jpg")
    oPB.Visible = True
    oPB.Width = 100
    oPB.Height = 100
    oPB.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage


    FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(oPB)

End Sub
```

Comment: You are (still) dragging one thing but wanting to work with another.  If you want to use that DragDrop code, then just `DoDragDrop()` using text and whatever file name each PB represents.  You arent *really* working with the PB dropped, so go with text.

Comment: I know, that's part of the question, how do I check what item is being dragged? If x is dragdrop then ... ElseIf Y is dragdrop then .. else ... End If

Comment: put "square.jpg" in the drag clipboard when they drag PB1, to load that image from file.  you need to look at the `DragEventArgs` (`e`) to see what you put there and you arent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already got the answer in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34093841/17034):

```
Private Sub FlowLayoutPanel1_DragDrop(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As _
                                      System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles FlowLayoutPanel1.DragDrop
    Dim oPB As New PictureBox()
    Dim pb = CType(e.Data.GetData(GetType(PictureBox)))
    oPB.Image = pb.Image
    pb.Image = Nothing     '' Optional
    '' etc...
End Sub
```

You do have a bug, the probable reason why you did not use the answer:

```
Private Sub PictureBox3_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox3.MouseMove
    ' Initiate dragging.
    PictureBox3.DoDragDrop(PictureBox2, DragDropEffects.Copy)
End Sub
```

Note how it drags the wrong control, PictureBox2 instead of PictureBox3.  You avoid bugs like this by writing DRY code, Do not Repeat Yourself.  The *sender* argument of a MouseMove event already gives you a reference to the control.  So you just need *one* event handler for all three controls:

```
Private Sub PictureBox_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove, PictureBox2.MouseMove, PictureBox3.MouseMove
    ' Initiate dragging.
    Me.DoDragDrop(sender, DragDropEffects.Copy)
End Sub
```

With the detail that we now let the Form support DoDragDrop().  Which only matters if you implement the GiveFeedback or QueryContinueDrag events.

Comment: Thanks Hans, i'm fairly new to all this and just didn't see it as you write it now! This is more clear. I have updated the question with another problem ive encountered using the drag drop could you please advise?

Comment: This is not a subscription service and you cannot invalidate my answer by changing the question.  Click the Ask Question button, you already know what it looks like.